# Research trends on mean curvature flow

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, flows, research

It's been a few months since I've been curious about mean curvature flow and now I'm reading [Robert Haslhofer's lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.7765). I like the subject and would like to do research on it, but I know neither where to start nor current research trends.

Can anyone explain the main threads of research in this area, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know [Lecture notes on Mean Curvature Flow by Carlo Mantegazza](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9783034801447)? The chapter $5$ of this has some research directions. I don't know well the research directions of MCF, but this chapter must be read with carefully, because this book was published in $2011$ and some problems may have been resolved, for example, the author comments on section $5.3$ about Mean Curvature Flow with surgeries that given $\phi_0: M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ an initial immersion of a hypersurface $M$ two-convex,

Comment: it's possible do a surgery on $M$ under MCF for $n \geq 3$, he cite the [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-008-0148-4) and states that the same problem it's an open problem for $n = 2$, but this problem has been solved recently [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.1461) on $2013$ and Robert Haslhofer and Bruce Kleiner gives a short proof for the same problem [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.2332) on $2014$.

Comment: I forgot to say, but Robert Haslhofer and Bruce Kleiner solved the problem for $n \geq 2$.